# The type or namespace name 'Vector' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public float speed = 3.5f;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector(63, 15, 51); 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

       transform.Translate(Vector3.right *horizontalInput *speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

`

i tried googling the problem i found solutions but i am not making a typo , also 'Vector3' and Time.deltaTime wasnt being highlighted

Comment: I'm not a Unity dev, but it looks like [Vector3](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) is a `struct`, so you'll have to create a variable of type `Vector3`. Maybe instead of `Vector3.right` you want `transform.right` ... ?

Answer (score 1):

> The type or namespace name 'Vector' could not be found

the only vector i see, is

```
transform.position = new Vector(63, 15, 51);
```

maybe change it to:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(63, 15, 51);
```

the update function looks good, are you sure that the error occurs there?